# Can someone please explain the concept of Super Message and Multiplier

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, sms

After trying to understand the Super Message bundles from the link [Super Message Bundle](https://www.salesforce.com/content/dam/web/en_us/www/documents/legal/Agreements/product-specific-terms/marketing-cloud-super-message-bundles.pdf)
I am not sure what does it mean when it says - "Messages sent to countries not
listed in the table below are not supported and will be charged at a multiplier of 75"

If the messages sent to non listed countries are not supported why will they be charged? Will they be delivered?

Anybody who has done SMS program for multi country implementation and how did they work towards getting it estimated will be great help.

Comment: The ones not listed are not 'not supported' in the sense of not able to be sent to. They just dont have the support, etc. from SFMC. The others do and are all bundled together into an 'other' category with the listed multiplier on super message cost

Answer (score 2):

Unsupported countries can sometime be delivered through partners in the SFMC ecosystem, and, in that situation, you will pay the partner the platform/messaging costs, and SFMC will fire an API